# Javascript For Loop with 2 itierators which increment at different values

Tags: javascript, for-loop, google-apps-script

**Question:** How can a for loop with 2 different variable incrementing at different amounts entirely be created?

**Premise:** I am attempting to look through an array and match it to any of many values of another array. One array is constant, the other may vary. Here is my work around: *(The goal is to accomplish the same result, while not repeating all of the if/else if statements)*

```js
function theFunctionImAskingAbout() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ms = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = ms.getRange("A:A").getValues().filter(String).length;
  var range = ms.getRange(1, 1, lastRow);
  var data = range.getValues();
   for(i = 0; i <= lastRow-1; i++){
if(data[i].toString().search(/Item1/)>-1)
    ms.getRange(i + 1, 2).setValue('Item1');
  }   
  else if (data[i].toString().search(/Item2/) > -1) {
    ms.getRange(i + 1, 2).setValue('Item2');
  }   
  else if (data[i].toString().search(/Item3/) > -1) {
    ms.getRange(i + 1, 2).setValue('Item3');
  }   
  else if (data[i].toString().search(/Item4/) > -1) {
    ms.getRange(i + 1, 2).setValue('Item4');
  }   
  else {
    ms.getRange(i + 1, 2).setValue("")     
  }   
};
```

Comment: I approved your edits, and bookmarked your link, thank you.

Comment: Please fix  `for (i = 0; i - 1) {` and supply the first, missing, `if` statement.

Comment: The question isn't very clear, but since you're using regexes you could go with `data[i].toString().match(/Item\d+/)` (or `/Item[1-4]/` if you need to limit to these values) then use the matched value in `setValue` method.

Comment: @Traktor53 I've fixed, thank you.

Comment: @pawel I need to check a value in ROW1 COLUMN1 against an array of values, and when done do the same thing in ROW2 COLUMN1. The difficulty is getting the second variable to itierate through the entire array while keeping i at 0 and only when done iterating through the array, add one to i. Does this help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

isn't it easier to just have 2 for loops inside one another?

```
for(i = 0; i <= lastRow-1; i++){
   for(j = 0; j <= ItemArray.length; j++){
       if (....)
       ...
   }
}
```

/syntax may be wrong/

Comment: But would this result in J incrementing through the entire array before I increments?